# Select Multiple Counts from multiple JOIN table that has multiple Group_BYs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL getting correct result:

```
SELECT 
companies.name as company_name, 
locations.country_code as location,
ad_messages.ad_template_name as creative, 
impressions.width as width,
impressions.height as height, 
count('impressions.id') as impressions 
FROM "impressions" 
INNER JOIN "ad_messages" ON "ad_messages"."id" = "impressions"."ad_message_id" 
INNER JOIN "visitors" ON "visitors"."id" = "ad_messages"."visitor_id" 
INNER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."visitor_id" = "visitors"."id" 
INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."visitor_id" = "visitors"."id" 
WHERE (visitors.user_id = 171) 
 AND (impressions.created_at >= '2016-03-17 16:17:20.241276' 
 AND impressions.created_at <= '2016-05-16 16:17:20.241336') 
 GROUP BY 
 companies.name, 
 locations.country_code,
 ad_messages.ad_template_name, 
 impressions.width, 
 impressions.height 
 ORDER BY 
 companies.name, 
 locations.country_code,
 ad_messages.ad_template_name, 
 impressions.width, 
 impressions.height
```

I get the result (count of impressions) grouped and subgrouped the company_name, locations and ad_messages.

[Impressions only Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mef04.png)

I can repeat the process for clicks and get result ( count of clicks ) grouped and subgrouped by different filters like so:

```
SELECT 
companies.name as company_name, 
locations.country_code as location,
ad_messages.ad_template_name as creative, 
ad_clicks.width as width,
ad_clicks.height as height, 
count('ad_clicks.id') as ad_clicks
FROM "ad_messages" 
INNER JOIN "ad_clicks" ON "ad_clicks"."ad_message_id" = "ad_messages"."id"
INNER JOIN "visitors" ON "visitors"."id" = "ad_messages"."visitor_id" 
INNER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."visitor_id" = "visitors"."id" 
INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."visitor_id" = "visitors"."id"
WHERE (visitors.user_id = 171) 
 AND (ad_clicks.created_at >= '2016-03-17 16:17:20.241276' 
 AND ad_clicks.created_at <= '2016-05-16 16:17:20.241336') 
 GROUP BY 
 companies.name, 
 locations.country_code,
 ad_messages.ad_template_name, 
 ad_clicks.width, 
 ad_clicks.height
  ORDER BY 
 companies.name, 
 locations.country_code,
 ad_messages.ad_template_name, 
 ad_clicks.width, 
 ad_clicks.height
```

However - I would like combine both impressions and clicks in one Query, I tried :

```
SELECT 
companies.name as company_name, 
locations.country_code as location,
ad_messages.ad_template_name as creative, 
impressions.width as width,
impressions.height as height, 
ad_clicks.width as click_width,
ad_clicks.height as click_height, 
count('impressions.id') as impressions,
count('ad_clicks.id') as clicks
FROM "ad_messages" 
INNER JOIN "impressions" ON "impressions"."ad_message_id" = "ad_messages"."id"
INNER JOIN "visitors" ON "visitors"."id" = "ad_messages"."visitor_id" 
INNER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."visitor_id" = "visitors"."id" 
INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."visitor_id" = "visitors"."id"
LEFT JOIN "ad_clicks" ON "ad_clicks"."ad_message_id" = "ad_messages"."id" 
WHERE (visitors.user_id = 171) 
 AND (impressions.created_at >= '2016-03-17 16:17:20.241276' 
 AND impressions.created_at <= '2016-05-16 16:17:20.241336') 
 GROUP BY 
 companies.name, 
 locations.country_code,
 ad_messages.ad_template_name, 
 impressions.width, 
 impressions.height,
 ad_clicks.width, 
 ad_clicks.height
```

This gave me totally wrong results! count(impression) and count(ad_clicks)had the same value. Is there any way I can get correct counts from one SQL?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`count(col_name) over (partition by .... order by ...)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html) like this, use `select distinct` instead of `group by`. And try using `alias` instead of `full_table_name`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    companies.name as company_name, 
    locations.country_code as location,
    ad_messages.ad_template_name as creative, 
    impressions.width as width,
    impressions.height as height, 
    ad_clicks.width as click_width,
    ad_clicks.height as click_height, 
    count('impressions.id') over (partition by companies.name, locations.country_code, 
            ad_messages.ad_template_name, impressions.width, impressions.height 
            order by    companies.name, locations.country_code, ad_messages.ad_template_name, 
            impressions.width, impressions.height)  as impressions,
    count('ad_clicks.id') over (partition by companies.name, locations.country_code, 
            ad_messages.ad_template_name, ad_clicks.width, ad_clicks.height 
            order by companies.name, locations.country_code, ad_messages.ad_template_name, 
            ad_clicks.width, ad_clicks.height ) as clicks
FROM "ad_messages" 
INNER JOIN "impressions" ON "impressions"."ad_message_id" = "ad_messages"."id"
INNER JOIN "visitors" ON "visitors"."id" = "ad_messages"."visitor_id" 
INNER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."visitor_id" = "visitors"."id" 
INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."visitor_id" = "visitors"."id"
LEFT JOIN "ad_clicks" ON "ad_clicks"."ad_message_id" = "ad_messages"."id" 
WHERE (visitors.user_id = 171) 
     AND (impressions.created_at >= '2016-03-17 16:17:20.241276' 
     AND impressions.created_at <= '2016-05-16 16:17:20.241336') 
ORDER BY 
    companies.name, 
    locations.country_code,
    ad_messages.ad_template_name, 
    impressions.width, 
    impressions.height,
    ad_clicks.width, 
    ad_clicks.height
```

A test in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/8703)